# "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" when initializing Gekko module in function

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I'm trying to write a function that, given a set of parameters, uses Gekko to solve an optimal control problem. For whatever reason, whenever I run this function, it gives this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-92ece108f7ea> in <module>
      1 import gekko as GEKKO
----> 2 solve_system()

<ipython-input-6-9d154ef663e4> in solve_system(theta, alpha, rho, chi, L_bar, n, w, delta_inc, xi, phi, tau, kappa, GAMMA, T, SIGMA, BETA, s_init, i_init, r_init)
     26 
     27     ##### initialize model #####
---> 28     m = GEKKO()
     29 
     30     ##### parameters #####

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I was looking into it and it seems to generally be [an issue with the way you import the package/module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094613/python-module-object-is-not-callable), but I did this similarly (but not in a function) previously and had no issues. I have no idea where to start solving it: any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html) I think the import is supposed to be:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thank you, rdas!

Answer (score 1):

You can import `gekko` a couple different ways to create a model `m`.

**Method 1**

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
```

**Method 2**

```py
import gekko as gk
m = gk.GEKKO()
```

**Method 3**

If you want to use some of the other modules like the [chemicals](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chemical.html) or [deep learning](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/brain.html) objects in `gekko` you can use something like:

```py
from gekko import gekko, chemical, brain
m = gekko()
c = chemical.Properties(m)
b = brain.Brain(m)
```

**Method 4**

Although it is possible, you should never do the following because of potential namespace conflicts with other imports:

```py
from gekko import *
m = GEKKO()
```

BTW, great question! I recommend keeping the answer by rdas as the accepted response because it is the minimal correct solution. I just included these other options here for reference.